# How do I get each different string of the input?

Tags: php, string

I'm working on my PHP to get the list of strings by using domdocument. I need your help as I got a problem with the strings.

When I get the list of strings for the input, I keep getting the same strings over and over when I output them on my PHP.

Here is where you can see in the output that I keep output the same strings:

```
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">
<channel id="101 ABC FAMILY">
<display-name>101 ABC FAMILY</display-name>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140507180000" stop="
20140507183000">
<title lang="en">Reba - Meet the Parents</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140507183000" stop="
20140507190000">
<title lang="en">Reba - Meet the Parents</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140507190000" stop="
20140507193000">
<title lang="en">Reba - Meet the Parents</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140507193000" stop="
20140507200000">
<title lang="en">Reba - Meet the Parents</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140507200000" stop="
20140507203000">
<title lang="en">Reba - Meet the Parents</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140507203000" stop="
20140507210000">
<title lang="en">Reba - Meet the Parents</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</tv>
```

It supposed to be what it would look like:

```
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">
<channel id="101 ABC FAMILY">
<display-name>101 ABC FAMILY</display-name>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140507180000" stop="
20140507183000">
<title lang="en">he Middle - The Telling</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140507183000" stop="
20140507190000">
<title lang="en">he Middle - The Wedding</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140507190000" stop="
20140507193000">
<title lang="en">Melissa & Joey - More Than Roommates</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140507193000" stop="
20140507200000">
<title lang="en">Melissa & Joey - Accidents Will Happen</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140507200000" stop="
20140507203000">
<title lang="en">Melissa & Joey - Right Time, Right Place</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140507203000" stop="
20140507210000">
<title lang="en">Baby Daddy - Curious Georgie</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</tv>
```

Here is the list of strings for the input:

```
The Middle - The Telling

The Middle - The Wedding

Melissa & Joey - More Than Roommates

Melissa & Joey - Accidents Will Happen

Melissa & Joey - Right Time, Right Place

Baby Daddy - Curious Georgie

John Tucker Must Die(D,L,V,S)

The 700 Club

Baby Daddy - From Here to Paternity

Reba - Meet the Parents
```

Here is the PHP:

```
    <?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    $errmsg_arr = array();
    $errflag = false;


    function getState($string)
    {
      $ex = explode(" ",$string);
      return $ex[1];
    }

    $xml .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
    $xml .= '
    <tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">';
    $baseUrl = file_get_contents('http://www.myownsite.com/get-listing.php'
    );

    $domdoc = new DOMDocument();
    $domdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
    $domdoc->recover=true;
    @$domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);
    $links = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('a');
    $i = 0;
    $count = 0;

    $data = array();
    foreach($links as $link)
    {
      if($link->getAttribute('href'))
      {
        if(!$link->hasAttribute('id') || 
$link->getAttribute('id')!='streams')
        {
          $url = str_replace("rtmp://", "", $link->getAttribute('href'));
          $url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $link->getAttribute('href'));
          $sdoc = new DOMDocument();
          $sdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
          $sdoc->recover=true;
          @$sdoc->loadHTMLFile($url);
          $query = parse_url($url)['query'];
          $channel_split = explode("&", $query)[0];
          $channel = urldecode(explode("=",$channel_split)[1]);
          $id_split = explode("&", $query)[1];
          $my_id = urldecode(explode("=",$id_split)[1]);
          $xpath = new DOMXpath($sdoc);      
          $programme_arr = array();     
          $time_arr = array();

          for ($i = 1; $i < 70; $i++)
          {
            $time_arr[] = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time".$i."']");
            $programme_arr[] = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='title".$i."']");
          }

          foreach($programme_arr as $programme)
          {
            $programme1 = $programme->item(0)->nodeValue;
          }
          $programme_title = $programme1;


          // Generating to make the XML File
          $xml .= "
      <channel id='" . $my_id. " " . $channel . "'>";
          $xml .= "
        <display-name>" . $my_id. " " . $channel; 
          $xml .= " </display-name>";

          // Save the output format
          $DATE_FORMAT_STRING = "YmdHis";

          // GET the current STAGE
          $current_state = getState($array[0]->nodeValue);
          $offset = 0;
          $flag = 0;

          foreach($time_arr as $time)
          {
            // Get the item state.  
            $this_state = getState($time->item(0)->nodeValue);

            // check if we past a day? 
            if($current_state == "PM" && $this_state == "AM")
            {
              $offset++;
            }
            $this_unix = strtotime($time->item(0)->nodeValue) + (60 * 60 * 
24 * 
    $offset);
            $values[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix);
            $starttime = $values[$count];

            if($flag>0)
            {
              $xml .= '
      <programme channel="'.$my_id. ' ' .$channel.'" start="'.$stoptime.'" 
    stop="'.$starttime.'">';
              $xml .= '<title lang="en">'.$programme_title;
              $xml .= ' </title>';

              $xml .= '
        <sub-title lang="en">';
              $xml .= ' </sub-title>';
              $xml .= '
        <desc lang="en">';
              $xml .= ' </desc>';
              $xml .= '
        <category lang="en">';
              $xml .= ' </category>';
              $xml .= '
      </programme>';
              $stoptime = $starttime;
            }
            else
            {
              $stoptime = $starttime;
              $flag=1;
            } 
            $current_state = $this_state;
            $count++;
          }

          $xml .= '
      </channel>';
        }
      }
    }
    $xml .= '
      </tv>';
    // output the xml to the browser in this example, write $xml to a file 
    here...
    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
    echo $xml;
    $handle = fopen("myChannel.xml", "w"); 
    fwrite ($handle, $xml);
    ?>
```

The problem are lie somewhere in this code:

```
foreach($programme_arr as $programme)
{
  $programme1 = $programme->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
$programme_title = $programme1;

xml .= '<title lang="en">'.$programme_title;
```

I tried to use `$xml .= '<title lang="en">'.$programme_title[$count];`, `$programme_title = $programme1[$count];` but it will not output each different strings.

Can you please tell me how I can get each different strings for the input without getting the same strings over and over?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by this example:

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```